# Message: Object of class CI_DB_mysqli_result could not be converted to int (Codeigniter 3)

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I just trying to make pagination in CI, this is the error

> Message: Object of class CI_DB_mysqli_result could not be converted to int
>
> Message: Object of class CI_DB_mysqli_result could not be converted to number

this is my controller buku

```
{
    $data['link_admin'] = 'active';
    $config['base_url'] = base_url() . 'admin/buku/';
    $config['total_rows'] = $this->model->get_table('tbl_buku');
    $config['per_page'] = 10;
    $config['first_tag_open'] = '<li class="page-item">';
    $config['first_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['last_tag_open'] = '<li class="page-item">';
    $config['last_tag_open'] = '</li>';
    $config['full_tag_open'] = '<div class="pagination pagination-sm m-0 float-right">';
    $config['full_tag_close'] = '</ul></div></div>';
    $config['num_tag_open'] = '<li class="page-item">';
    $config['num_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['cur_tag_open'] = '<li class="page-item active"><a class="page-link" href="#">';
    $config['cur_tag_close'] = '</a></li>';
    $config['next_link'] = '&rarr;';
    $config['next_tag_open'] = '<li class="page-item">';
    $config['next_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['prev_link'] = '&larr;';
    $config['prev_tag_open'] = '<li class="page-item">';
    $config['prev_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $this->pagination->initialize($config);

    $data['offset'] = $this->uri->segment(3);
    $data['query'] = $this->model->get_all_paginate_book('tbl_buku', 'id', $config['per_page'], $this->uri->segment(3));
    $data['id'] = "KB".str_pad($config['total_rows']+1, 4 ,0,STR_PAD_LEFT);
    $data['kategori']    = $this->model->get_table('tbl_kategori');

    $data['title'] = "Data Buku | Perpustakaan";
    $data['title2'] = "Data Buku";
    $data['users'] = $this->db->get_where('users', ['email' => $this->session->userdata('email')])->row_array();

    $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
    $this->load->view('templates/topsidebar', $data);
    $this->load->view('admin/buku', $data);
}
```

[this is the view code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QsATr.png)

Comment: You have quite a few queries. If you want help you'll need to narrow it down to the offending query and post the code for it. Then as an additional measure you should `print_r()` the query result. The most likely cause is one of your queries is failing or not returning what you think it is.

Comment: Additionally you can turn on `db_debug` in database.php which might yield more information on what is occuring.

Comment: Hi alex its still same

Comment: again, you are going have to *narrow* down to the offending query and post the code as well as the result for that query. we cannot help you otherwise.

Comment: Could you also post the `get_table` method on the model ? also avoid posting images of code, paste the code directly